# Having issue for load test scripting for application implemented using silverlight and CSLA

Tags: silverlight, azure-devops, load-testing, csla

We are testing application which is implemented using Silverlight. The development team has used CSLA for encryption and decryption of request and response body. A message body is in an encrypted format, we are facing issues for co-relation and parameterization. 
Anyone having experience of load testing for such kind of application? We are using VSTS 2015

Comment: What do you mean VSTS 2015? Do you mean Visual Studio 2015 or Team Service?

Comment: Basically what we need to know: Are you using TFS (on-premise) or VSTS *cloud), If TFS, what version of TFS are you using? What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: And you do know that Silverlight is high on the deprecation list, right? all browsers except IE11 and IE10 are no longer supported.

Comment: Right now we are using both the ways, on-premises as well as VSTS cloud. But as this issue is during the first phase of load test activity i.e. scripting, it is not dependent on the tool. @jessehouwing - yes I agree Silverlight is on high deprecation list, but the application is already in use we have to cover the load testing for that component as well.

Comment: Then the Visual Studio version remains. So are you using visual studio 2015?

Comment: Yes, we are using Visual studio 2015, but we have tried with VS 2017 too.

Answer (score 0):

Csla is not an encryption; rather it is a framework for development of business objects.  One of the key features is that the object can move across the network, so that the same business rules run on both the Silverlight client and the Asp.net server (which is where you data access will occur).  It does this by serializing the objects using HTTP, WCF or some other protocol back and forth.

If the calls you are load testing do not require a user to be authenticated, you should be able to capture them with something like Fiddler and replace them.  If the calls are authenticated, you may encounter issues as Csla automatically can serialize the Silverlight appdomain's IPrincipal so its available on the server as well. That may or may not cause problems with your load testing, but it would depend on how exactly the authorization and authentication was implemented.